# Gridview show empty row

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Linq-to-SQL, and when I select my record to show in gridview my gridview shows empty records. I can see the row but they are empty

```
public class showFacReq
{
            public string documentNumber;
            public string fixPaperNumber;
            public string letterDate;
            public string letterNumber;
            public string propertyFactoryCenteralId;
            public string requestId;
            public string year;
}

public List<showFacReq> ShowFactoryRequset()
{
    List<showFacReq> q = (from i in dbconnect.tblFactoryRequests.AsEnumerable()
                          select new showFacReq
                                         {
                                             documentNumber = i.documentNumber,
                                             fixPaperNumber = i.fixPaperNumber,
                                             letterDate =ConvertToPersianToShow(i.letterDate),
                                             letterNumber = i.letterNumber,
                                             propertyFactoryCenteralId = i.propertyFactoryCenteralId,
                                             requestId = i.requestId.ToString(),
                                             year = i.year
                                         }).ToList();
    return q;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn all the fields of your class to properties. Only properties are exposed. Like this:

```
public class showFacReq {
  public string documentNumber {get;set;}
  //do the same for others
  //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having columns in your gridview and bind each individual property of your record to each column. Like `Record.documentNumber, Record.fixPaperNumber` etc.